# How to pass a regex from an array - to string, when using .join('') FOR EXAMPLE ["X","-","M","E","N"]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Create an underscore for every letter of the word.  This is an example of what I want to achieve (word is "Doodle"):

```
Doodle = _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Now, I have a word that has a hypen (e.g. "X-men").  How would I code it so that the output will be:

```
_ - _ _ _
```

I want to pass the hyphen.  I know this has something to do with regex can someone help with explaining this process

Comment: `['X', '-', 'M', 'E', 'N'].map(c => c === '-' ? c : '_').join(' ')` - of course, a regex and string replace would work too

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was most impressed by the solution that was done excellently by @swivel and @ tiagodws below - they even left out an option to add characters I want to exclude after '^' - check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could:

```
["X", "-", "m", "e", "n"].join("").replace(/[^-]/g, "_")
```

This will join the array into a string and replace everything except for hyphens with underscores.

Add every character you want to exclude after the `^`.

Comment: Additionally, if you wanted to include all special characters, something like this would only strip out the alpha-numeric characters: `myArr.join('').replace(/[0-9A-Za-z]/g, "_")` ... As an example, if `myString = "O'Connor"`, the result would be `"_ ' _ _ _ _ _ _"`

Comment: It's exclusive rather than inclusive; the reverse of @tiagodws's solution which is to turn anything that isn't a hyphon into an underscore. Rather this turns anything that IS an alpha numeric character into an underscore.

Comment: Thought I'd just throw some options out there :)

Comment: Forgot the quotes in your `.join()`, which would have resulted in a string of `"X,-,m,e,n"`. Added them in, but the edit required more than six characters, so I elaborated a little bit. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Swivel Thank's, forgot it after editing to better answer the original question :P

Comment: Absolutely! Glad to help :)

Comment: @Swivel THANKS! Im inspired with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep any special character, and not just hyphens, the following should work:

```js
var word = "doodle";
var word2 = "x-men";
var word3 = "jack & jill"

var reg = /[0-9a-zA-Z]/gm

console.log(word.replace(reg, "_"))
console.log(word2.replace(reg, "_"))
console.log(word3.replace(reg, "_"))
```